# "Prefix found" error while extracting RAR file with Archive Manager

Tags: 18.04, archive, rar, file-roller

I have a RAR archive file, and I get this "Prefix found" error message when I try to extract its contents using the built-in Archive Manager (file-roller 3.28.0) in Ubuntu 18.04:

[image: An error occurred while extracting files. Prefix found]

I would assume that if it can read the archive's file list, then it could also extract the files. I was able to extract the file using the `unrar` command in the terminal, but I would still like to know what's wrong with Archive Manager, and if there's a way to fix it so that it can extract RAR files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem depends on missing "unrar" package.
To solve on "debian like" system:

```
sudo apt install unrar
```

or

```
sudo apt install unrar-free
```

Answer (score 3):

When you install unrar in Ubuntu, it came with unrar-free too. This not should be a problem.

You're problem might be caused by permissions restrictions.

Try to use unrar from a terminal with:

```
sudo unrar e <file_name>
```

This will unrar the **.rar** file in the same directory of the file.